# Retrieving values for each key in JS Object and pushing each set of values for each key to it's own array

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, javascript-objects

I want to iterate through my key/value pairs and push all the values for each key into its own array. These arrays of values of each key should be pushed to a single output array.

I hope this explains what I'm trying to do:

```
Input: map = {"hi":["hello","hey","howdy"],"bye":["Goodbye","Ciao"]}

Output:  output = [["hello","hey","howdy"],["Goodbye","Ciao"]]
```

This is what I have so far:

```
return Object.keys(map).reduce((output, key) => {
      return output.push(map[key])
  },[])
```

Any help on iterating through the values for each key and adding those values to an array within another output array would be greatly appreciated.

For background, this is part of a grouping anagrams problem so I'm populating my Map as follows from a provided array "str" of strings.

```
 let map = {};
  str.forEach(anagram => {
    const sortedWord = anagram
      .split("")
      .sort()
      .join("");
    map[sortedWord] = map[sortedWord] || [];
    map[sortedWord].push(anagram);
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

All you need is the built-in [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

> `Object.values()` returns an array whose elements are the enumerable property values found on the object.

```js
const map = {"hi":["hello","hey","howdy"],"bye":["Goodbye","Ciao"]};
const output = Object.values(map);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce the return pushs to 'output' no need to push yourself:

```
  return Object.keys(map).reduce((output, key) => {
      return map[key]
  },[])
```

You could also use map:

```
  return Object.keys(map).map((key) => {
      return map[key]
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the above two excellent answers, you may choose to use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), which will return an array from the input object's `[key, value]` pair. From there, we can return only the `value` into the resulting array, giving you the expected result.

```js
const input = {"hi":["hello","hey","howdy"],"bye":["Goodbye","Ciao"]}
const result = Object.entries(input).map(item => item[1]);

console.log(result);
```

However, do take note that `Object.entries()` is not supported by Internet Explorer browsers.

Alternatively, you may use the good old [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) statement to iterate through the enumerable properties of the object, followed by pushing the corresponding values to the resulting array.

```js
const input = {"hi":["hello","hey","howdy"],"bye":["Goodbye","Ciao"]}

const result = []
for (const property in input) {
  result.push(input[property]);
}

console.log(result);
```